# Link csv file to HTML by reading the csv file with Python and then making the HTML table

Tags: python, csv, flask, error-handling, html-table

I try to link a csv file to an HTML table by usign Python and Flask:

1. I call a function to open and read the csv file
2. I call a function to make an HTML table with the csv data
3. I place the html table on a html page

When I run the code below I get the following error message : csvallissues_to_html_table () missing 1 required positional argument : "mydata"

Could you please provide me some guidance

```
@app.route("/seeall")
def csvallissues_to_html_table(mydata, headers = None, delimiter=","):
    html_page = get_html("seeall")
    #call the csv file and read it
    mydata = "data.csv"
    with open(mydata) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    #reading file content into list
    rows = [x.strip() for x in content]
    table = "<table border =1>"
    #creating HTML header row from csv file if header is provided 
    if headers is not None:
        table+= "".join(["<th>"+cell+"</th>" for cell in headers.split(delimiter)])
    else:
        table+= "".join(["<th>"+cell+"</th>" for cell in rows[0].split(delimiter)])
        rows=rows[1:]
    #Converting csv to html row by row
    for row in rows:
        table+= "<tr>" + "".join(["<td>"+cell+"</td>" for cell in row.split(delimiter)]) + "</tr>" + "\n"
    table+="</table><br>"
    return html_page.replace("$$TABLE2$$", table)
```

Comment: When you call the function, you should provide the "mydata" argument. In your case, you could try to remove "mydata" from the function's declaration (as you assign its value on line 5)

Comment: Thank you for your help ! It's working perfectly now.